# Availability of compiler variables for installer helper script

Tags: install4j

We are using install4j in version 6.0.4. When we put compiler variables to the helper script of an installation application like

`options.add(new String[] {"-VmyOption=[Value]", "Set the custome option (default=" + context.getCompilerVariable("myoption") + ")");`

we get a NullPointerException for the context variable. Is it a bug or is the context not available at the time the helper script will be called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> or is the context not available at the time the helper script will be called

That is indeed that case. The script is called before the environment is initialized, so the context parameter is null.

Comment: Thank you. As an improvement I would approve to disable the selection of installer- and compiler-variables for this screen otherwise more developer could be confused by that.

Comment: This script property is an outlier, no other script property is invoked with a null context object. The real fix would be to remove the context parameter for it, but we had decided to not add such a mechanism for just one property. In the help text it mentions that the context object will be null. I've added this to our issue tracker for reconsideration.